# How to render different forms on show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have Event model with a `kind` column. The Event can be either a training camp, conference, etc.
Right now on every event page I display a form for a Customer so that a client can register for this particular Event. Customer `belongs_to` Event.

Now, I would like to have a new kind of Event and for this specific event I need to display additional fields in the form for the customer. Customer table does not have these columns. The fields should be like location, training date, parent name, parent phone, etc.

Of course, the new fields should be validated upon input. I know how to render different forms conditionally on the event show page but I am not quite sure where to add the new columns and how to handle it in the controller. I wouldn't like to add these columns to Customer table because I think they do not really belong there.
Besides, I need to validate the new fields as well so there will be a situation where I render different forms and I can't validate all the fields if just one specific form is rendered.

Do you have any ideas how I could go about this?

Answer (score 1):

**User attr_accessor in customer model for mass assigning the new fields**

```
attr_accessor: :location,:training_date etc
```

Now you pass those values from form with model object . And you can right condition in "Pratial or View"

If you want store those values in DB table then you have to create columns in Customer Model. Or if you don't want to create fields in customer table then you can use "**Redis**" for storage the values.

Comment: If I add the new columns to Customer, how would I go about validating them conditionally in each specific scenario? For example, if the event is a training, do not validate those extra fields, if it is a conference validate different fields.

Comment: once you have added attr_accessor then you can write validation for those fields in model . like using "validates ", other wise you can use custom validations . Or else you can use JavaScript if it is applicable to you .

Comment: surely you can use custom validations. Like below code.
validate :customer_event
def customer_event
    -- here you can write your condition --
    if self.event == "training"
       --- do ----
    end
end

Comment: If you have any doubt on custom validations then lemme know I will update the answer . Thank you

Comment: `if self.event == "training"` does not work - `undefined variable or method 'self'` I tried also `if event == training` but got `undefined variable or method 'event'`. Could you help me?

Comment: I've figured it out: ` if: Proc.new { |c| c.event == 'training' }`

Comment: Yes I missed that. Good one